# Page doesn't update while JavaScript is executing code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a visualization for the Knight's tour problem. The algorithm I made works recursively. If I enable JavaScript, the page won't load (at least in Chrome).
http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/knightstour/knightstour.htm

Why won't the page load? How can I fix this? I know my implementation probably isn't the most efficient way to calculate solutions, but I'm still in school and I haven't got the time and experience to come up with more efficient algorithms. I'm just doing it because the visualization of the problem is fascinating to watch.

Comment: Not a solution, but if you insert an `alert` after the first `writeBoard`, you can then click "OK", let the next alert pop up, click "Don't let this page show any more popups", and then click "OK" again. The algorithm will then run through for at least a little while.

Comment: I noticed the same thing, but that would be a bad workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers pause the page loading while they execute inline scripts.  You script is probably caught in an infinite loop.

You should wrap your code in a function, and call the function when the page loads (onLoad event).

**EDIT**

The OP has already made this change.

Comment: @Ryan Kinal, It didn't yesterday when I gave my answer.  It didn't occur to you that the OP might have taken some feedback and made changes to his page?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it recursively there is no point for the browser to update the UI. A way to implement the recursion and let the UI refresh could be to use `setTimeout()` and have a short timeout that would let the UI do something while the JS is idle.

Comment: I tried the timeout, but it doesn't do away with the problem. Also, shouldn't the page rendering engine and the JavaScript interpreter be able to work simultaneously?

Comment: I need to update the UI during the recursion, because I wanna be able to see the progress of the algorithm. That's the whole point of the visualization.

Answer (score 1):

this is the first thing that jumps out at me:

```
setTimeout(knightsTour(newX, newY, board, visitedFields), 10);
```

you are calling the method `knightsTour` immediately here, rather than after the timeout. `setTimeout` takes a function reference and a delay. you can fix your statement by wrapping the actual call in an anonymous method

```
// method to generate an function reference with properly scoped variables
var fnGenerator = function(newX, newY, board, visitedFields) {
    var wrapperFn = function() {
        knightsTour(newX, newY, board, visitedFields)
    };
    return wrapperFn;
}

// call the generator and return the wrapping function
var fnToCall = fnGenerator(newX, newY, board, visitedFields);

// Go from there
setTimeout(fnToCall, 10);
```

so we're generating a new function which wraps your actual call to `knightsTour` and provides the correct parameters. using a seperate function for this is necessary since you're trying to call all this in a loop if you didn't do this every call to `knightsTour` would use the same values for the parameters (see javascript closures).

after this your board will load and your sequence will start.

Comment: I've changed this on the local copy I created, and it appears to at least allow the page to render. I'm unfamiliar with the "Knight's Tour" problem and its solutions, so I don't know what it's supposed to look like, but this is a step in the right direction at the very least. +1

Comment: looks like there's more to fix but I'm running to lunch. I'll look at it some more later if nobody else chimes in.

Comment: Been reading up on the Knight's Tour problem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_tour - and hoping that the OP isn't trying to implement the brute force solution.

Comment: @Ryan: I created that page to watch the algorithm do its job - in a visual way. I know this algorithm will take a really long time to finish but that's not the point. I don't want to know how many solutions there are for the 8x8 board, I just want to watch the algorithm work.

Comment: There may be an issue with using `setTimeout`: Once it is called, the rest of the current function will continue to execute. It won't follow the "wind, recurse, unwind" order that you want. In fact, it will most likely go "wind, unwind, recurse", which is likely your problem. It will still recurse with the correct values, but your board state will be screwed up.

Comment: Well that stinks. Is there any other approach you could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Your title explains the problem exactly. As long as the script is running, there is nothing else happening in the browser.

To see the progress of your script, you have to divide the process into small parts, so that you can execute one part of it and then return control to the browser long enough for it to display the result of that part.

You can use the `window.timeOut` method to return control to the browser and have the browser continue your code as soon as possible.

Example:

```
function workPart1() {
  // Do one part of the process here
  // Then let the browser update, and make it start part 2 after that:
  window.setTimeout(workPart2, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display the knight's moves visually on the webpage. If you execute your entire algorithm at once, all you will see is the final move after your code completes execution.

You need to modify your algorithm so that it maintains variables indicating the current state of the algorithm, and every time the function is called, it computes the next move. Then you can either use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with some delay or have the user click a button to advance to the next move.